# Where is my Wordpress feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, rss2

I have done research and it all tells me my Wordpress site should actively support RSS feeds.

But going to:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/feed

Doesn’t work. What step am I missing?

## Update

If I try to open on an iPhone:

[image: iphone]

If I click cancel then nothing happens. If I click open:

[image: results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per website link, I have checked and it looks like working perfectly.
Here i have sent screenshot
[Feed page screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kgGb.png)

Comment: Hmm. On my iPhone it says to see it in news. If I say no, nothing happens. If I say yes, nothing can be shown.

Comment: Ok, so it is not compatible with News on iPhone. I used Feedely.